# Who was the guru of Chanakya?

Tags: history, philosophy, guru, india

We all know Chanakya a.k.a Kautilya, the author of Arthashastra.
I would like to know that, who was his Guru and which school of thought did he follow?

Comment: This question is off-topic.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Why?? When we can know about gurus of other known personalities why not him? Please don't straightaway down vote without giving others chance to explain.

Comment: This is best suited on [history.se]. Chanakya is not a religious figure.

Comment: Purely suited to https://history.stackexchange.com/ site. Down vote because the OP doesn't seem to have a look at the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Can you please edit and explain how is it related to Hinduism?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta When we can have questions about Arjun, Karna and their gurus from mythological epics then why can't we have knowledge about his guru, of a real person who has done so much for his nation and he himself being a brahmin Hindu?

Comment: "Their gurus from mythological epics" in which mythology Chanakya is mentioned?

Comment: So you didnt read the comment properly, I said why not of a real person. Do read it again @KrishnaShweta

Comment: For questions about real persons, there is History Stack Exchange. Not all questions about Hindus are on-topic here. This is about Hinduism. Chanakya did for his nation. But we are not a national site and he is not related to HInduism. You can ask the question on aforementioned site.

Comment: With due respect there is no point arguing, if you want you can flag it off like others. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this question is off topic.OP clearly wants to know which Hindu philosophy Chanakya belonged to.